# How to delete words which start with some specific pattern in a file in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I want to delete all words in my file that start with **3:** and **4:**

For Example -

**Input is**

```
13 1:12 2:14 3:11
10 1:9 2:7 4:10 5:2
16 3:7 8:24
7 4:7 6:54
```

**Output should be**

```
13 1:12 2:14
10 1:9 2:7 5:2
14 8:24
7 6:54
```

Can someone tell me if it is possible using sed command or awk command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]][34]:[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]*/ /g' YourFile
```

Posix compliant and assuming there is no (as in sample) first word stating with 3: or 4:.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\b[34]:\S*\s*//g' file
```

Looks for a word boundary and then either `3` or `4` followed by `:` and zero or more non-spaces followed by zero or more spaces and deletes them throughout the line.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        {if (! sub("^[34]:", "", $i)) d=d$i" "}
        print d; d=""
     }' file
```

It loops through the fields and just store in the variable `d` those that do not start with `3:` or `4:`. This is done by checking if `sub()` function returns true or not. When the loop through the line is done, the `d` variable is printed.

For your given file:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if (! sub("^[34]:", "", $i)) d=d$i" "} print d; d=""}' file
13 1:12 2:14 
10 1:9 2:7 5:2 
16 8:24 
7 6:54
```

Comment: This will leave an extra space everywhere a field is removed.

Comment: I updated now with another approach that does not leave spaces, just in the end of line.

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed -r 's/ 3:[0-9]*| 4:[0-9]*//g'


$ cat input.txt
13 1:12 2:14 3:11 10 1:9 2:7 4:10 5:2 16 3:7 8:24 7 4:7 6:54


$ cat input.txt | sed -r 's/ 3:[0-9]*| 4:[0-9]*//g'
13 1:12 2:14 10 1:9 2:7 5:2 16 8:24 7 6:54
```

Explanation:

- `-r` = Regex search
- `3:[0-9]*`: Search for a space, then 3, then :, then [0-9] or a number between 0 and 9, the * means that he will search for zero or more hits in the pervious regex search, which is [0-9], so * means on this case that will search for zero or more numbers behind the first number after :
- `|` : Means OR
- `4:[0-9]*`: Same as above except that instead of 3 it will search for 4
- `//`: The substitution strings, if you put POTATOE behind bars it will type it, on this case, sed will simply don't type anything.
- `/g`: Search in all the input passed to sed.

Comment: Alternation is not necessary in this case as `3|4` can be replaced by `[34]`. However this will not remove any such strings at the beginning of a line as it is looking for a space at the beginning of the regexp.

Comment: Potong is partially right :) Alternation is not needed, but if we assume that the first number on each row will never have a : behind then it will works fine. Anyway, here you have a shorter version  sed -r 's/ [34]:[0-9]*//g'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all words contains : and has at least one digit after the :

```
sed "s/ \([34]:[^\b]+\)//g" inputfile
```

This matches SPACE, 3 or 4, colon and then at least one non word boundary. It replaces it forth nothing and does so for the whole line.

Comment: The opposite of `\b` is `\B` however it is an anchor not a character and can be used in this context.